# what is EOF in cygwin in windows 10

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin

I used to run cygwin on win8.1, and while giving inputs to a program CTRL-Z used to denote EOF. Today I installed cygwin on win10, and ran "a.out". After typing in the input data, when I press CTRL-Z I get the message "Suspended" and I get back the shell prompt. I tried this with bash and csh, same result. CTRL-D also does not work, it is killing the shell.

Just to confirm that it is only this problem and nothing else, I created a new input.txt file, and entered the relevant input data in it, and ran "a.out < input.txt", and it worked fine. So the problem is only in defining EOF for STDIN.

How to solve this problem?

**Note:** I am closing this question, and put in more details in a new question [reading till EOF in java on cygwin on windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327818)

Comment: ctrl-z is the unix command to suspend the process. Have you considered MSYS? ctrl-D works there.

Comment: Check the way the keyboard driver generates signals with `stty -a` (look for `eof` under `cchars`).  You can change the settings using `stty` as well, but I don't recommend that.  CTRL+D "kills the shell" because you are sending the shell EOF.    You could use `set -o ignoreeof`

Comment: Jean-Francoise: I am using cygwin, not msys.

Comment: cdarke: I used ignoreeof, see my comment below.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix-like systems, including Cygwin, Ctrl-D is (by default) configured to trigger an end-of-file condition when reading from a tty (terminal/keyboard). It's possible to change this using the `stty` command, but it looks like you haven't done that (and you almost certainly shouldn't).

If you enter Ctrl-D while running your program that reads from standard input, that will likely terminate your program, depending on how it responds to reaching the end of its input.

Ctrl-Z sends a signal that suspends your current program (some programs, such as interactive shells, are able to handle or ignore that signal). (Windows uses Ctrl-Z to trigger end-of-file.)

The behavior you describe indicates that you're typing Ctrl-D at a shell prompt. This gives the shell, not your program, and end-of-file condition. The shell response to this by terminating (by default; you can use `set -o ignoreeof` to tell the shell to ignore it).

If you type Ctrl-D *while running your program*, it should correctly trigger and end-of-file condition and cause your program to terminate.

UPDATE: Normally you should type Ctrl-D either before any other input (resulting in the program receiving no input at all), or immediately after typing Return. To trigger end-of-file in the middle of a line, you'd have to type Ctrl-D *twice*. (This is usually not a great idea, since it results in the program seeing a partial line with no terminating newline character.)

Comment: Ctrl-Z used to work as EOF in my laptop using win8.1. In the new laptop using win10, and with a new installation of cygwin, this is not working anymore.  As advised, I now did "set -o ignoreeof". Now when I press Ctrl-D after the relevant inputs, nothing happens (looks like the Ctrl-D is simply ignored), and when I press Ctrl-Z I now get the message "Stopped" instead of "Suspended". But either way, the program stops at that point, and does not print its expected outputs. No, I have not used stty.

Comment: What is the output of `stty` (with no arguments)?

Comment: speed 38400 baud; line = 0;
ixany

Comment: @R71: Sorry, try `stty -a`. The output should include something like `eof = ^D`. Ctrl-Z triggers an end-of-file condition *under  Windows*. Under any Unix-like environment (including Cygwin, even though it runs under Windows), Ctrl-D should trigger and end-of-file condition. And you need to pay close attention to whether you're typing Ctrl-D to your program or to the shell.

Comment: Thanks. "stty -a" reports "eof = ^D; susp = ^Z". So now I am confused. I run the program (a.out) and type in the inputs, then press ^D, and nothing happens, the program seems to be waiting for further input (Why??). Whereas, when I run "a.out < input.txt", where the relevant inputs are in a text file, then it works correctly and prints its outputs. Is this a problem with win10, because as per stty the configuration seems to be correct?

Comment: Adding one more detail (though may not be relevant for this discussion), the program I am running is "java org.antlr.v4.gui.testRig" on the Hello example of antlr4. For this discussion, we may treat this as just a.out.

Comment: Do you type Ctrl-D in the middle of a line? To trigger end-of-file, you need to type Ctrl-D either at the very beginning (empty input) or immediately after typing <Return>. You can type Ctrl-D twice in the middle of a line, but that means the program will see a partial line with no terminating newline. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am typing Ctrl-D immediately after <Return>.

Comment: `cat` is another program that reads from standard input. If you type `cat` at a shell prompt, then type the three letters `x`, `y`, `z`, then <return>, then <Ctrl-D>, then `cat` will terminate. Please try that and confirm that it behaves as I described. Then run your program and give it exactly the same input. What happens?

Comment: I wrote a small program in c++ to read inputs till EOF, and ^D worked fine for it. So it seems that the reported problem has to do with the antlr code. Thanks for the stty hint, which helped to point to the problem area.

Comment: So what did your program do with that input? If you've figured out the problem, post an answer so others can benefit.

Comment: You say *Ctrl-Z used to work as EOF in my laptop using win8.1.* .... but this was certainly not the case with **cygwin** programs. Perhaps you were executing a non-cygwin program from a cygwin shell (bash, zsh, fish,....). I'm running Cygwin on Windows 7, and Control-Z certainly does **not** cause EOF.

Comment: @Keith: I dont have an answer yet. Posted a generic question for this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327818