# reading till EOF in java on cygwin on windows-10

Tags: java, cygwin

I am using a java utility (antlr) on cygwin, the java is the windows version and I run javac/java from the cygwin bash.

The following java code used to work on cygwin on win8.1, to read a series of numbers from stdin till EOF (adapted from [reading input till EOF in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927326)):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            num = in.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%d\n",num);
        }
    }
}
```

Recently I got a new win10 laptop, installed cygwin on it, and it does not work anymore. When I press Ctrl-D, the program continues to wait for input, it is not taken as an EOF.

After some debugging (see comments in [what is EOF in cygwin in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309965)), "stty -a" reports "eof = ^D; susp = ^Z", so the Ctrl-D is expected to be seen as EOF. The following equivalent code in c++ works as expected, possibly because this code is compiled with cygwin itself and hence treats ^D as EOF.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i=0, status;
    for(;;) {
      printf("Enter a value %d:\n", i);
      status = scanf("%d", &i);
      if(status!=1) break;
    }
}
```

So something seems to be broken in the combination of cygwin-win10. Any hints, on what can be broken and how to fix it?

NOTE: I am using java jdk-7u72

When using cygwin, I use the java installation of windows itself. Here are the usages:

**In cygwin:** javac Hello.java; java Hello

Then give the inputs, followed by ^D in a new line (ie immediately after entering Return.

**In windows:** I also tried running the same program in windows, just to make sure whether it is a windows or cygwin problem. So here also I run: javac Hello.java; java Hello

Then give the inputs, followed by ^D (or ^Z) in a new line (ie immediately after entering Return). And the program terminates correctly, when I press ^D or ^Z.

Comment: How do you compile and run the Java program? Do you use the `java` command to run it? Is the `java` command a Cygwin executable? What do `type java` and `file $(type -p Java)` say?

Comment: There is no Cygwin Java. So it is a Windows Java interaction with cywin

Comment: @Keith: See additional notes above, I am using the java installation in windows itself, including its CLASSPATH. "type java" gives "java is hashed (/cygdrive/c/sw/jdk7u72/bin/java)". And the second command gives: "/cygdrive/c/sw/jdk7u72/bin/Java: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows"

Comment: @matzeri: Yes, it is a windows java interaction with cygwin. But in windows it works fine, as I have now mentioned above. But does not work in cygwin.

Comment: Can you update the question to make it clear just what you're doing and what happens? The fact that you're using the Java installation in Windows itself needs to be part of the question. In the **In cygwin** section, please say what happens after you type Ctrl-D. In the **In windows** section, you say "^D (or ^Z)"; do *both* cause the program to terminate?

Comment: @Keith: added the info in the problem statement.

Comment: The **In cygwin** section still doesn't say what happens. To be clear, you're saying that when you run a Windows program outside Cygwin, it still treats Ctrl-D as end-of-file? Are you sure? That's surprising.

Answer (score 0):

In a non-Cygwin Windows program, Ctrl-Z on input triggers an end-of-file condition.

In a Cygwin program, one that uses the Cygwin DLL, Ctrl-D on input triggers and end-of-file condition. (This can be reconfigured with the `stty` command, but you haven't done that.)

It doesn't matter how the program is executed. It only matters how it was built.

The program you're running is the `java` command, which is a non-Cygwin Windows executable. (The `java` command happens to be running your Java program.) Since `java` is a non-Cygwin Windows program, it treats Ctrl-Z as the end-of-file character.

As far as I can tell, all the behavior you describe is consistent with that.

If you want Java programs to act like Cygwin programs, you'd have to use a Java system built to use Cygwin. I'm not sure whether that's feasible, but it's beyond the scope of this question, so I'll leave that to you and a Google search.

Comment: Your 4th para holds the key, since java is a non-cygwin windows program, it treats ctrl-z as EOF. However, cygwin is configured to treat ctrl-z as suspend (as "stty -a" has reported), so maybe that is the problem. (Not sure how ctrl-z used to work as EOF in my earlier 8.1 installation.) Can I configure this using stty? If yes, how?

Comment: You're running a non-Cygwin program from a Cygwin shell. I don't know whether Cygwin  intercepts Ctrl-Z (as suspend) before it's seen by the Windows program (as end-of-file) or not, and I don't have a Cygwin system to test it. You might experiment using your C++ program compiled by a non-Cygwin compiler.